# do recopy a string to a new string have more performance impact that recopy an array?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am new to Java and I do not know which is better
So I got a very strange homework question asked us to split the csv into 2d-array but their're 2 rules
 1. you **can't use** `ArrayList`
 2. You **can't import** other java class other than `file.io`

So this make it very challenging since we can't tell the array size yet. So when I `readline`, I decided to store it in a string first
after finished all the `readline`, only then I process the ","

So I wonder, do recopy a string to a string to add text have more performance impact or recopy previous array to new array is inefficient?
This is just an example what the csv may look like
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6

```
stringRecopy &= reader.readLine()
```

vs

```
int[][] arrayRecopy = (copy previous array with new reader.readLine().split(",") here)
```

Comment: "do recopy a string to a string to add text have more performance impact", you can always try it yourself, do it in 1000 iteration or so if the difference is negligible

Comment: @Martheen - Half right.  The problem is that it is very easy to get misleading results if you write a micro-benchmark by hand.  The OP needs to read this as well: [How do I write a correct benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/)

Comment: If I have to guess blindly I say copy previous array to a new array because there is new data will be slower, what do you think?

Comment: I think it is more complicated than that.  (Think about it.  That is roughly what `ArrayList` does!)

Comment: What does `file.io` mean? There is no package nor class of that name. Besides that, it looks like a rule that is easy to dodge. You can always use classes by their fully qualified name, without `import` statements.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

Unless the requirements for your homework assignment *explicitly* say that performance is the most important criteria, performance is a red herring.

In the real world, the important things about *most* programs<sup>1</sup> are:

1. They do what they are supposed to do; i.e. functionally complete, no bugs.
2. They are maintainable; i.e. someone else can read and understand the code, and fix or modify it.
3. They are implemented efficiently ... in terms of programmer time.
4. They are *fast enough* for their intended purpose.

*"As fast as possible"* is rarely a criteria.  Not least because achieving *"as fast as possible"* usually involves ignoring criteria 1 through 3 above.

---

So how does that apply here?

Well, what you are doing is worrying about the efficiency of a program that doesn't need to be efficient.  Indeed, if I was marking this assignment<sup>2</sup>, I would pay a lot more attention to 1 and 2 than to performance.  A program was written to be fast at the expense of maintainability would be down-marked!

---

So how would I implement it?

Well, the professional way would be to use `ArrayList`.  But that is not an option<sup>3</sup>.

So that leaves two approaches:

- Read (or process) the input twice.  In the first pass work out how big the 2D array needs to be (by counting lines and the max number of commas in a line).  Then create the array and do a second pass to populate the array.
- Implement the code to *grow* the arrays as required.

Your criteria for deciding which approach to choose should be based on which one you think is easier >>for you<< to write, and for someone else to understand.  Performance should be unimportant.

---

Finally, I don't think we can answer your actual question without seeing completed versions that implement **both** of your approaches.  It very much depends on how you code them.

But once you *have* coded them and tested and debugged them, it should not be difficult to measure them.  See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/) for advice on how to do it in a way that will give you valid answers.

---

<sup>1 - There are notable exceptions to this.</sup>

<sup>2 - Note that I won't be marking your assignment, so you would be advised to think about what your teachers are actually looking for.  If you are in doubt, you could ask them.</sup>

<sup>3 - This is not a criticism of the homework.  I fully understand why they have made this restriction.  This exercise is about learning to program, not (so-called) "best practice" programming in the real world.</sup>

Comment: I know, unable to use ArrayList made it hard. String and array is the most commonly used thing isn't it? So I figured smone must had done the benchmark before, that is why I ask. I know performance is not important, but I'm just curious to know which method is better

Comment: *"So I figured smone must had done the benchmark before, that is why I ask."* - I don't know if someone has done benchmarked this.  Have you tried googling for a relevant benchmark?  Benchmarks are only relevant if they pertain to the way that you implement your code.  We can't see your code ...